# Python pandas - Replace string of Zeros in series

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a pandas dataframe with a date variable with dates formatted like this "2011-01-11 01:11:11.111111+00." However, some dates with 0 for the timestamp are formatted like this ""2011-01-11 00:00:00.+00."

I have written a simple function to strip the last 10 digits leaving only the date and time with no decimals. But before stripping, I need to standardize the dates with 0 for time to have the same number of characters as all other dates.

So far I tried this code, but no change occurred. No error message was given.

```
df['time'] = df['time'].replace({"00:00:00+00":"00:00:00.000000+00"}, regex=True).
```

I also tried it with regex=False and tried using str.replace instead.

P.S. here's my function to strip digits:

```
def strip_n_chars(df, col, n): 
    values = df[col]
    df[col]= values.str[:-n]
```

Does anyone now how I can replace the 0 timestamps? Or know of another way to strip all dates to end up like "2011-01-11 00:00:00"?

Comment: You need to set regex to False.  The plus sign in your string is interpreted as a repeating character

Comment: James, thanks for the comment. However, even with regex set to false, no change occurs. Do I also need to modify the string to replace?

Answer (score 0):

The first step should probably be to get the `df['time']` column into a Timestamp if that's not already done, by using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).
Then you can use the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to output the format you like using [the strftime method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html).
For example:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['nice_date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%x %X') #2011-01-11 00:00:00
```